# Make REST API on Meteor+React without other packages

Tags: json, reactjs, meteor, url-routing

For example, when the path is

```
/json/users/4
```

meteor app must return json something like

```
{
    id: 4,
    name: 'Alex'
}
```

I'm using **reactrouter:react-router** for client routing. I know about **reactrouter:react-router-ssr**, but how to use it to response raw json? And make it not conflicting with existing client routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Meteor's default **Webapp** package will help ([doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp)):

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/hello", function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world from: " + Meteor.release);
});
```

I put this in server folder. Other routes will be rendered as they was.
So, there is more useful example (es6):

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/payme", function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            const body = chunk.toString();
            if (body.length < 1e6) {
                const params = body.split('&').reduce((result, item) => {
                   const [key, val] = item.split('=');
                   //do it for utf-8 values (I use it for cyrillic strings)
                   result[key] = unescape(decodeURI(val)).replace(/\+/g, ' ');
                   return result;
                }, {});                      //post method params

                //do something and get resulting json

                res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
             } else
                 res.end(JSON.stringify({error: 'too big query'}));
        });
    } else
        res.end(JSON.stringify({error: 'isnt post req'}));
});
```

**req.query** can be used to get **GET** params.