# Meteor react publish raw json

Tags: python-3.x, meteor

I am trying to scrape my own meteor-react application.

However, when I have a simple json on "http://localhost:3000/export_json", which publishes:

```
{"greetings": "hello"}
```

With Python 3 I try to read the content with `urlopen`:

```
url = "http://localhost:3000/export_json"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html.read()
```

Instead of the json I get a whole page:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>`\n  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="__meteor-css__" href="/merged-stylesheets.css?hash=a899d6ca37c7cf0b13ba96f881073946529354d0">\n<title>\n    ThisIsMyTitle\n  </title>\n\n</head>\n<body>\n\n\n\n<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent ...`
```

which probably has to do with the reactivity of Meteor+react but I cannot figure out how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot publish an plain JavaScript object. You must publish a [*cursor*](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#mongo_cursor).

What you want is to create a [method](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html), and use that when connecting to your endpoint, using tools like [Picker](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/picker) or [`simple:json-routes`](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/json-routes). See [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API) for more examples and approaches.

```
JsonRoutes.add("get", "/posts/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  var id = req.params.id;

  JsonRoutes.sendResult(res, {
    data: Posts.findOne(id)
  });
});
```

Comment: that helps a lot! But the Picker tool does not work with react-router unfortunately. Is there a solution for Meteor+react and `react-router`?

Comment: this solved my issue! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462946/make-rest-api-on-meteorreact-without-other-packages but your advice def helped me in the right direction

Comment: Nice! Just FYI, I checked on one of my projects I did in the past, and I used [`simple:json-routes`](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/json-routes). I think that abstracts the `webapp` package further and it's really easy to use.